# Wordpress - include php file and call it with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have added a javascript code in a PageBuilder of a page in my wordpress site.
This code will do an ajax call to a PHP file, like this:

```
var check = function(a) {
$.ajax({
    url: 'dwload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {a:a},
    success: function(data) {
        if(data === 'NOK'){
            alert('OK');
        }else{
            window.open(data);
        }
    }
});
};
```

i modified the index.php file in the root folder:

```
include '/dwload.php';
```

and added the dwload.php file in the root folder.

but when i call the ajax function, i get the error 404, not found.

how can i solve the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest that you use the standard way for ajax in wordpress (https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). If for some very particular reason you can't do that then try to insert the full url (ht tp s: / /example.com/dwload.php) in your url parameter. If you don't have any other problems (htaccess and/or file permission) you should be able to see that

Answer (score 0):

I don't have reputation enough to comment, so I will answer, I think you just first check the permissions of file. The server must be able to execute thee file, and this can make some trouble. [You can see more here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-file-permissions/).